# How to use StringComparison for strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string-comparison, ignore-case

```
string body = Selenium.GetBodyText();

if (body.Contains("software", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   //do something
}
```

I get a `string does not contain a definition for Contains` message when I do the above. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance everyone!

I am trying to check if body has the string "software", "Software" or "SOFTWARE". body will contain paragraphs and paragraphs of text (string).

Comment: you have string body, then using bodyText, if it is not a typo post the declaration of bodyText

Comment: oops...sorry...that's a mistake. Let me fix it quick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expression to match a string search in C#. You also have the option to ignore case.

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

This link might be useful: [How to: Search Strings Using Regular Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 12):

I don't believe `string` has an overload of [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) taking a `StringComparison`. However, you could use `IndexOf` [which does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx):

```
if (body.IndexOf("software", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
```

Comment: wouldn't the error message indicate that he is using an older framework? It seems the error message would be different if the method signature was wrong.

Comment: @0A0D: Good point - it should be "No overload for method Contains takes 2 arguments". I guess we'll see what Maya says :)

Comment: @Maya Another possibility would be to extend the `String` class with an extension method using code like above.  You would essentially be creating your own overload.

Comment: @Maya: I'm sorry Maya, I hope you are not offended. It was meant as generality.

Comment: body is a string, and when I do body.Contains, I see 3 overloads - one taking char, another taking string, and the last one taking char with StringComparison. You are right Jon. Thanks! I am not sure how to check the version of what framework I am using.I will try using IndexOf.

Comment: @ 0A0D: That's ok :) I'm not offended. Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: @Maya: I do not see the three overloads you are talking about. What IDE? In VS 2010, I see the standard Contains(string) method and another one using IEnumerable.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if you are using .NET 1.1, but it did not contain the method `Contains`. You have to use `IndexOf`. .NET 2.0 added the method [Contains (per MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). With [IndexOf, you can use StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

String.Contains only take one parameter - your code should be

```
bodyText.Contains("software");
```

Answer (score 2):

`Contains` has only one parameter - the string it is comparing against. Did you mean, `Equals` which does take a `StringComparison`?

Answer (score 1):

From the code what has been pasted, you are declaring a variable "body" of type string and using another variable "bodyText" which is undeclared.

Answer (score 1):

String doesn't have a Contains method with that signature.  str.Contains(chr, StringComparison), not str.Contains(string, StringComparison)...

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always make an extension method (if you're using .Net 3.5 or higher):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a value indicating whether the specified String object 
    /// occurs within this string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string object being extended</param>
    /// <param name="value">string object to check for</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">StringComparer to use</param>
    public static bool Contains(this string str, string value, StringComparer comparer)
    {
        StringComparison comparison;
        if (comparer == StringComparer.CurrentCulture)
            comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture;
        else if (comparer == StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
        else if (comparer == StringComparer.InvariantCulture)
            comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCulture;
        else if (comparer == StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
        else if (comparer == StringComparer.Ordinal)
            comparison = StringComparison.Ordinal;
        else if (comparer == StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            comparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        else
            comparison = StringComparison.Ordinal;

        if (str.IndexOf(value, comparison) != -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Contains provided you compare it after converting it to same case(UPPER or lower)

eg:

```
"samplestring".ToUpper().Contains("SAMPLESTRING")
```

Comment: Not a good idea, due to the way some cultures handle upper-casing. For example, `"mail".ToUpper().Contains("MAIL")` may not return true.

Comment: thanks skeet.didn think over. how about converting the argument too to uppercase and comparing. ("samplestring".ToUpper().Contains("samplestring".ToUpper()))

Comment: I'm not even sure whether that will work. Basically performing case-insensitive matching ideally shouldn't involve conversion, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to this party, but hopefully I can save someone from the hole I was just in.

With .net core 2.1 overload `Compare(String, StringComparison)` was made available. As of this writing, if you're using .net Framework or an earlier version of core, you'll need to use a different solution out lined here.

Grip: Could MSFT please keep the framework selector in one place on the [api docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-2.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_System_StringComparison_)? Used to be top and center and the "Applies to" is very misleading.